# parametrized function returning ModuleWithProviders in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

I have an app consisting of several components of which each defines its own subset of route states. Depending on the application that integrates these components they (the *app*) provide parent state under which some component states should be placed. I.e.

Component states:

```
[{
  name: 'component',
  url: '/component',
  component: ComponentRootComponent,
  abstract: true,
  default: '.list'
}, {
  name: 'component.list',
  url: '',
  component: ComponentListComponent
},...]
```

This is some app section module:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: ...,
  imports: [
    UIRouterModule.forChild({ states: SECTION_STATES }),

    SomeComponentModule,
    UIRouterModule.forChild({
      states: RouterUtil.setParentState(SECTION_STATES[0].name, SOME_COMPONENT_STATES)
    })
  ]
})
export class AppSectionModule {}
```

`setParentState()` function merely iterates through component states and prefixes them with parent state name, so they fall below that specific route state.

This is all great, but instead of adding two imports for each of my components I thought it would be better if I provided a function with my modules that would allow me to have a single but configurable import per component.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: ...,
  imports: [
    UIRouterModule.forChild({ states: SECTION_STATES }),
    SomeComponentModule.importFor(SECTION_STATES[0].name)        
  ]
})
export class AppSectionModule {}
```

`importFor` should therefore return `ModuleWithProviders` type which is a wrapper for my original component module that shuld also define component routing and place it under specific parent route:

```
export class SomeComponentModule {
  public static importFor(parentState: string): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: SomeComponentModule,
      providers: [
        // what do I do here?
      ]
    };
  }
}
```

**How do I implement such a function?** I don't know how should I be calling or prividing `UIRuterModule.forChild(...)` within this function? That's the main problem I'm trying to resolve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking what UIRouterModule actually does, this seems to work as expected:

```
export class SomeComponentModule {
  public static importBelowState(parentState: string): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: SomeComponentModule,
      providers: UIRouterModule.forChild({ states: RouterUtil.setParentState(parentState, SOME_COMPONENT_STATES) }).providers
    };
  }
}
```

So now I it is possible to import component module while also configuring its route states as in the question:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: ...,
  imports: [
    UIRouterModule.forChild({ states: SECTION_STATES }),
    SomeComponentModule.importBelowState(SECTION_STATES[0].name)        
  ]
})
export class AppSectionModule {}
```

Answer (score 0):

By using a "hidden" module you can accomplish this.

The first module has a forRoot() or in your case a importFor()
Which has an ngModule which points to a hidden module.

This module is what gets calls imported when calling importFor.
It then imports the original module and also exports it to make it appear hidden.

I find this a good way to make reusable modules that I can simply drop into my project and everything gets configured with both reducers, effects, routes and all :)

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    SharedModule,
  ],
  declarations: [
    ...SHARED_COMPONENTS,
  ],
  exports: [
    ...SHARED_COMPONENTS,
  ]
})
export class SecurityModule {

  // when the user imports SecurityModule.forRoot() in the app module what we really import is the RootSecurityModule
  // but it will also create the IsAuthenticated guard
  // it also imports all the feature stuff such as reducers, effects and routes

  // if we then later on need to access shared components from the SecurityModule we can import the module without the forRoot()
  static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: RootSecurityModule, 
      providers: [
        IsAuthenticatedGuard,
      ],
    };
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [

    // import the above module so that we get all the shared declarations
    SecurityModule,

    // import the "include once" modules for security
    StoreModule.forFeature('security', securityReducer),
    EffectsModule.forFeature([
      SecurityEffects
    ]),
    SecurityRoutingModule,
  ],

  // we need to export the SecurityModule otherwise SecurityModule.forRoot() will not mean the same thing as SecurityModule
  exports: [
    SecurityModule,
  ]
})
export class RootSecurityModule {}
```

Comment: You provided an example of your own code, which doesn't really apply as such to my problem. I would like to knowhow do I call `UIRouterModule.forChild()` in my `importFor` function so that I could provide configurable routing directly on the module itself instead of importing and mangling routes outside.

Comment: Your `forRoot` should have a parameter which you would use within the function body. That's what I need as I need to provide parent state so that I can then configure component states to fall below this provided parent state.